# Metrics-server is in CrashLoopBackOff with NEW install by rke

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have installed at least 10 times last one days, but its same every time
Everything runs fine but metrics-server  is in   CrashLoopBackOff

what I understand below section are missing from the pods YAML file and needs to add into Deployment.

I am  new to Kubernetes, I have 2 question

1. I am using rke to install rancher cluster, so why bellow setting will be  missing from pods  to start metric-server?

   Command:   /metrics-server
   --cert-dir=/tmp
   --secure-port=4443
   --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
   --kubelet-insecure-tls
2. what is the best way to add those lines , i am quite new so need some guidelines

#### Cluster information:

```
Kubernetes version:
[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS   ROLES               AGE   VERSION
192.168.0.56   Ready    controlplane,etcd   17m   v1.19.10
192.168.0.57   Ready    controlplane,etcd   17m   v1.19.10
192.168.0.58   Ready    controlplane,etcd   17m   v1.19.10
192.168.0.59   Ready    worker              17m   v1.19.10
192.168.0.60   Ready    worker              17m   v1.19.10
[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$
```

[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$ kubectl get pods metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57 -n kube-system -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.4.3/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.4.3/32
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-16T23:00:42Z"
  generateName: metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
    pod-template-hash: 5b6d79d4f4
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:generateName: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:k8s-app: {}
          f:pod-template-hash: {}
        f:ownerReferences:
          .: {}
          k:{"uid":"fb15b257-4a9d-478b-b461-8b61c165e3db"}:
            .: {}
            f:apiVersion: {}
            f:blockOwnerDeletion: {}
            f:controller: {}
            f:kind: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:uid: {}
      f:spec:
        f:affinity:
          .: {}
          f:nodeAffinity:
            .: {}
            f:requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              .: {}
              f:nodeSelectorTerms: {}
        f:containers:
          k:{"name":"metrics-server"}:
            .: {}
            f:args: {}
            f:image: {}
            f:imagePullPolicy: {}
            f:livenessProbe:
              .: {}
              f:failureThreshold: {}
              f:httpGet:
                .: {}
                f:path: {}
                f:port: {}
                f:scheme: {}
              f:periodSeconds: {}
              f:successThreshold: {}
              f:timeoutSeconds: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:ports:
              .: {}
              k:{"containerPort":4443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                .: {}
                f:containerPort: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:protocol: {}
            f:readinessProbe:
              .: {}
              f:failureThreshold: {}
              f:httpGet:
                .: {}
                f:path: {}
                f:port: {}
                f:scheme: {}
              f:periodSeconds: {}
              f:successThreshold: {}
              f:timeoutSeconds: {}
            f:resources: {}
            f:securityContext:
              .: {}
              f:readOnlyRootFilesystem: {}
              f:runAsNonRoot: {}
              f:runAsUser: {}
            f:terminationMessagePath: {}
            f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
            f:volumeMounts:
              .: {}
              k:{"mountPath":"/tmp"}:
                .: {}
                f:mountPath: {}
                f:name: {}
        f:dnsPolicy: {}
        f:enableServiceLinks: {}
        f:priorityClassName: {}
        f:restartPolicy: {}
        f:schedulerName: {}
        f:securityContext: {}
        f:serviceAccount: {}
        f:serviceAccountName: {}
        f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
        f:tolerations: {}
        f:volumes:
          .: {}
          k:{"name":"tmp-dir"}:
            .: {}
            f:emptyDir: {}
            f:name: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-08-16T23:00:42Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: {}
          f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: {}
    manager: calico
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-08-16T23:00:47Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Initialized"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Ready"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastProbeTime: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:containerStatuses: {}
        f:hostIP: {}
        f:phase: {}
        f:podIP: {}
        f:podIPs:
          .: {}
          k:{"ip":"10.42.4.3"}:
            .: {}
            f:ip: {}
        f:startTime: {}
    manager: kubelet
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-08-16T23:00:54Z"
  name: metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57
  namespace: kube-system
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4
    uid: fb15b257-4a9d-478b-b461-8b61c165e3db
  resourceVersion: "5775"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57
  uid: af8d4e07-aa3f-4efe-8169-feb37cfd97df
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: beta.kubernetes.io/os
            operator: NotIn
            values:
            - windows
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/worker
            operator: Exists
  containers:
  - args:
    - --cert-dir=/tmp
    - --secure-port=4443
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
    - --logtostderr
    image: 192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /livez
        port: https
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: metrics-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 4443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /readyz
        port: https
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 1000
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: tmp-dir
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: metrics-server-token-78b6h
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: 192.168.0.59
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 2000000000
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: metrics-server
  serviceAccountName: metrics-server
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: tmp-dir
  - name: metrics-server-token-78b6h
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: metrics-server-token-78b6h
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-16T23:00:43Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-16T23:00:43Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [metrics-server]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-16T23:00:43Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [metrics-server]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-16T23:00:43Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://344c587a7edd3abed035c12bfc16b9dbd0da3f26ba9101aa246bf4793648d380
    image: 192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6
    imageID: docker-pullable://192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server@sha256:c9c4e95068b51d6b33a9dccc61875df07dc650abbf4ac1a19d58b4628f89288b
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://e28b6812965786cd2f520a20dd2adf6cbe9c6a720de905ce16992ed0f4cd7c9e
        exitCode: 2
        finishedAt: "2021-08-16T23:21:47Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2021-08-16T23:21:18Z"
    name: metrics-server
    ready: false
    restartCount: 12
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2021-08-16T23:26:52Z"
  hostIP: 192.168.0.59
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.42.4.3
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.42.4.3
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2021-08-16T23:00:43Z"


[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$ kubectl describe  pods metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57 -n kube-system
Name:                 metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 192.168.0.59/192.168.0.59
Start Time:           Tue, 17 Aug 2021 00:00:43 +0100
Labels:               k8s-app=metrics-server
                      pod-template-hash=5b6d79d4f4
Annotations:          cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.42.4.3/32
                      cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.42.4.3/32
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.42.4.3
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.4.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4
Containers:
  metrics-server:
    Container ID:  docker://74ea122709aefc07b89dcbd3514e86fdff9874627b87413571d1624a55c32baa
    Image:         192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server@sha256:c9c4e95068b51d6b33a9dccc61875df07dc650abbf4ac1a19d58b4628f89288b
    Port:          4443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --secure-port=4443
      --kubelet-insecure-tls
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
      --logtostderr
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Tue, 17 Aug 2021 00:27:18 +0100
      Finished:     Tue, 17 Aug 2021 00:27:47 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  13
    Liveness:       http-get https://:https/livez delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get https://:https/readyz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from metrics-server-token-78b6h (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  metrics-server-token-78b6h:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  metrics-server-token-78b6h
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoExecuteop=Exists
                 :NoScheduleop=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  28m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57 to 192.168.0.59
  Normal   Pulling    28m                   kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6"
  Normal   Pulled     28m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6" in 4.687484656s
  Warning  Unhealthy  28m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "https://10.42.4.3:4443/readyz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  28m                   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.42.4.3:4443/livez": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  27m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "https://10.42.4.3:4443/readyz": dial tcp 10.42.4.3:4443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  27m (x5 over 28m)     kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  Unhealthy  27m (x5 over 28m)     kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Normal   Killing    27m (x2 over 27m)     kubelet            Container metrics-server failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Created    27m (x3 over 28m)     kubelet            Created container metrics-server
  Normal   Started    27m (x3 over 28m)     kubelet            Started container metrics-server
  Normal   Pulled     8m14s (x10 over 27m)  kubelet            Container image "192.168.0.35:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.6" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    3m15s (x97 over 25m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$



[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$ ^C
[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$ kubectl logs  metrics-server-5b6d79d4f4-ggl57 -n kube-system
I0816 23:27:20.011598       1 secure_serving.go:116] Serving securely on [::]:4443
[rke@rke19-master1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Failed with statuscode: 404` message suggests you are querying an address that does not exist.

We can see you are pulling some v0.3.6 tag of the metrics-server image. And although it comes from rancher, we could assume they stick to upstream versioning.

Checking changelogs in upstream, we can see that `/livez` and `/readyz` were introduced in v0.4.0, see: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/tag/v0.4.0

I would suggest you try querying the `/healthz` URL, which was removed from v0.4.0. Or change your httpGet probes for tcpSocket ones. Or: try to upgrade the metrics-server to a recent release?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, 
I am going to try with newever version of metric-server, will update very soo, however , how do i do this ?
"I would suggest you try querying the /healthz URL, which was removed from v0.4.0. Or change your httpGet probes for tcpSocket ones"

Comment: Check for a metrics-server Deployment in kube-system. If you don't find one, we know there's a ReplicaSet (as shown in your Pod ownerReferences). Edit the livenessProbe and readinessProbe. You should find a path: replace them with `/healthz`. Or replace the `httpGet` probe method, with a `tcpSocket`, where only the `port` argument is required / no need to go further than TCP handshake, won't care your server talks proper HTTP and doesn't return with an error code.

Comment: Hi Great!!! Thanks changing /healthz it works~
But why by default it was looking at the worng one ... should it be fix for  v0.3.6 from the product ?

Comment: IDK. For sure, something's wrong, either the image tag or the deployment definition. You could probably get in touch with Rancher, on GitHub, report your issue (pick a repo depending on how your cluster was deployed - the image tag suggests they're accountable for this)

Answer (score 0):

I've found probe timeouts on metrics-server too aggressive:

```
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readyz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /livez
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

What happens is metrics-server returns "ok" on both livez and readyz but the requests takes more than one second to process:

```
$ time curl -k https://SNIPPED:4443/livez
ok
real    0m3.081s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.005s
$ time curl -k https://SNIPPED:4443/readyz
ok
real    0m3.206s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.013s
```

Since 3 seconds is greater than 1 second, it's not "live" and not "ready". I've no idea why it's taking 3 seconds to respond but this the core issue why CrashLoopBackOff is happening.

The way to workaround this problem is to modify the timeout to, say, 5 seconds or 10 seconds. Use `kubectl edit metrics-server -n kube-system` to modify it in place.